# S_SESSION variable (user role) not recognised

Tags: php, session

Session login and start, with Session variables declaration and store:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['estado'] = "activo";
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
$_SESSION['us_type'] = $registro['us_type'];
$_SESSION['us_avatar'] = $registro['us_avatar'];
header('location:/gestion/panel.php');
```

Variable `$_SESSION['estado']` works fine as it loads content if it is *activo*, and if not locates to other directory:

```
if(($_SESSION['estado'] == 'activo')){
   ....
```

But it does not seem to recognise `$_SESSION['us_type']`, as even when Database has correct fieldname and value *(us_type, 1)* php does not load under this conditional, locating user as if it had no value 1 on us_type:

```
 if(($_SESSION['estado'] == 'activo') && ($_SESSION['us_type']== 1)){
   ....
```

Why is the reason for this? Even when status session variable is working fine..

edit:  $_SESSION value: Array ( [estado] => activo [usuario] => german [us_type] => [us_avatar] => )

Comment: print_r($_SESSION) what says??

Comment: Array ( [estado] => activo [usuario] => german [us_type] => [us_avatar] => )

Comment: why is it not taking these two values? I've checked DB and seems all ok...

Comment: as far I can see , us_type is not initialised or assigned any values

Comment: Can you post the code where you define the $registro array?

Comment: try print_r($registro) or share the piece of code for $registro

Comment: Solved. It was not $registro, it was $register. Silly mistae... thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

$registro['us_type'] is NULL try find why its is null. use var_dump() for find issue

Comment: Could it be because I created these two fields just some minutes before? I'll take a look.

Comment: Solved. It was not $registro, it was $register. Silly mistake... thank you for your attention.